# how can I start a bash script in its own process group

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, process-groups

I would like to start a bash script from another bash script, but start it in its own process group just like when you run it from the terminal.

There are a few similar questions, but I can't find an answer that matches my example.

Take these two scripts

```
$ cat main.sh 
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

echo if this has been started in its own group the following will pass
ps -o ppid,pgid,command $$
ps -o pgid | grep $$
echo passed

$ cat wrapper.sh 
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

./main.sh
```

When I run `main.sh` on its own, the terminal puts it in its own group:

```
$ ./main.sh 
if this has been started in its own group the following will pass
 PPID  PGID COMMAND
20553  1276 bash ./main.sh
 1276
 1276
 1276
passed
$ echo $?
0
```

but when I run `main.sh` from `wrapper.sh` my test fails
(as expected)

```
$ ./wrapper.sh 
if this has been started in its own group the following will pass
 PPID  PGID COMMAND
 2224  2224 bash ./main.sh
$ echo $?
1
```

But what do I have to put into either `wrapper.sh` or `main.sh` to make it run `main.sh` in its own group the same way it would if it does when it is run straight from the terminal?

(If it makes a difference, I am actually hoping to run `./main.sh &` in `wrapper.sh` but it was easier to run it in the foreground for this experiment.)

(I am using ubuntu 18)

Comment: Use `set -m` in `wrapper.sh`. But the real Q is why you need to run it in a separate process group -- keep in mind that neither session (`sid`) not process groups/jobs (`pgid`) work as process *containers*.

Comment: i want to simulate what control-c will do by sending SIGINT to the group

Comment: That seems to work.  Would you mind turning that into an official answer?

Comment: There are many pitfalls with using monitor mode from a script. For instance, in `bash -ic 'set -m; cat &'`, the cat will get an `EIO` error instead of being stopped by a `SIGTTIN` signal when trying to read from the controlling tty. I don't feel like making a list of all the problems related to that. But you can answer your own Q with a practical example of whatever worked for you ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming Bash, the immediate answer would be to enable "monitor mode" (job control) with `set -m`, or `-m` on the command line:

From the man page:

> `-m`      Monitor mode.  Job control is enabled.  This option is on by default for interactive shells on systems that support it (see JOB CONTROL above).  All processes run in a  separate process group.  When a background job completes, the shell prints a line containing its exit status.

```
$ bash -m wrapper.sh 
if this has been started in its own group the following will pass
 PPID  PGID COMMAND
12630 12631 bash ./main.sh
12631
12631
12631
passed
```

However, the question is rather tight on the "why", and there might be reasons monitor mode is disabled by default in non-interactive shells, so YMMV.

Comment: @rescdsk, d'oh. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `setsid`. It creates a new session for your process, which makes it the process group leader.

See `man 1 setsid` and `man 2 setsid`.